# Duvida com geração de valores randômicos

Tags: pascal

Estou com uma duvida com relação a um trabalho da faculdade que venho fazendo. Consiste em criar um jogo de batalha naval, em PASCAL. Estou usando o conteúdo desse link como guia para escrever o programa:

http://www.pb.utfpr.edu.br/omero/Pascal/Exercicios/Geral/BATALHA.Htm

A duvida é a seguinte, como estabeleço quantas posições uma determinada embarcação deve ocupar no tabuleiro?

Por exemplo, se desejo estabelecer que uma determinada embarcação ocupe 6 posições no tabuleiro devo escrever dessa forma?

```
for Conta := 1 to 5 do
begin
repeat
i := random(6);
j := chr(random(9)+65);
until Batalha[i, j] = '0';
Batalha[i, j]:='S';
end;
```

O comando  `i := random(6);` estabelece que determinada embarcação vai ocupar 6 posições no tabuleiro?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não é bem isso, veja o seu exemplo com comentários bem detalhados:

```javascript
{ Cria 5 (cinco) Submarinos. }
  for Conta := 1 to 5 do  // laço para o número de submarinos
  begin
    repeat
     //seleciona um número aleatório dentre as colunas (numéricas)
      i := random(6);  
      /* Seleciona uma letra aleatória (A -> J ) [9 letras]
      Isto e' : (número de 0 a 9) + 65 para converter o número em letra) 
      */
      j := chr(random(9)+65); 

    until Batalha[i, j] = '0';
    //adiciona o submarino (uma casa)
    Batalha[i, j]:='S';
  end;
```

De forma análoga, verá que no destroyer as casas são definidas da seguinte forma:

```javascript
//verifica se esta no começo do tabuleiro ou se o sucessor estará no começo
until (Batalha[i, j] = '0') and (Batalha[i, succ(j)] = '0');
//adiciona uma "parte" do destroyer no tabulero
Batalha[i, j] := 'D';
//continua a adicionar o destroyer
Batalha[i, succ(j)] := 'D';
```